# xpath select nodes inside comments

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to select `<title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>` using xpath within comments

```
<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<!--<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
-->

</bookstore>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a very reasonable question

Comment: @akhterwahab regex is not under consideration in my case.

Comment: @MikeYin you can pick comments using '//comment()' and can get desired part from this using any xpath string methods if regex is not under consideration

Answer (score 3):

Using XPath 3.0 you can do so by parsing the comment again using `fn:parse-xml`. This will result in a normal XML element, which you can now traverse with standard XPath expressions.

```
parse-xml(/bookstore//comment())/book/title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that as follows :

```
//bookstore/book/following::comment()[1]
```

This will result :

```
<!--<book>
<title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
   <price>39.95</price>
</book>
-->
```

Comment: This just gives you the comment, but not the `<title />` element.

Comment: @dirkk no, i don't think so. The expression will result the complete book element in comment, as shown.

Comment: That is just what I said. It returns the _whole_ comment, i.e. the `<book />` element, whereas the OP is just interested in the `<title />` element

Answer (score 0):

There are no nodes inside a comment. Comments just contain text. If you know that the content of a comment is well-formed XML, then you can read the text, pass it to an XML parser, and process the resulting tree. With XPath 3.0, or with processor extensions, you can do all of that within a single XPath expression.